# Increase the money when click Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
cpsecond = open("clickpersecond.txt", "r+")
cps = cpsecond.read()
cointotal = open("totalcoin.txt", "r+")
totalcoin = cointotal.read()

while True: # main game loop
...

    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        totalcoin += cps
        print("Your current coin is", totalcoin, end="\r")

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(30)
```

When i click, it doesn't increase the coin, it just adds the number near it like:

```
#Current Coin = 0

<<<Your current coin is 01 #1st Click

<<<Your current coin is 011 #2nd Click

<<<Your current coin is 0111 #3rd Click

<<<Your current coin is 01111 #4th Click

#0 = your current money
#1 = increases your money by +1
```

I want to make it that when you click, it increases your money and you can spend it ingame.

Comment: In other words, i wanna make it to when you click at anywhere it increases your ingame money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cps` and `totalcoin` are strings. Use [`int(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert the string to integral values :

```py
cpsecond = open("clickpersecond.txt", "r+")
cps = int(cpsecond.read())

cointotal = open("totalcoin.txt", "r+")
totalcoin = int(cointotal.read())
```